# Bulk file rename

Tags: linux, rename, macos

I have a large collection of files with filenames similar to:

```
myvideo.s01e01.episode.title.here.mp4
myvideo.s01e02.episode.title.here.mp4
```

I'd like to bulk rename them so I end up with:

```
myvideo.s01e01.mp4
myvideo.s01e02.mp4
etc.
```

I'm using macOS, but the files are on a network share, so they can also be addressed via linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(*.s<->e<->).*(.mp4)' '$1$2'
```

Remove `-n` (dry-run) when happy.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to `perl-rename` (called `rename` in some Linux distros, `prename` in others and `perl-rename` in yet others), you can do:

```
$ rename -n 's/(.+?\..+?\.).*\.(.*)/$1$2/s' *mp4
myvideo.s01e01.episode.title.here.mp4 -> myvideo.s01e01.mp4
myvideo.s01e02.episode.title.here.mp4 -> myvideo.s01e02.mp4
```

That will just print what the command would do without actually renaming anything. If the output is what you would expect, then run the command without the `-n` to actually rename the files.

If you don't have `perl-rename` and the file names don't contain newline characters and have all their bytes making up valid characters in the user's locale, you can also do it directly in the shell (here assuming a `zsh`-like shell and a BSD-compatible `sed` implementation):

```
for f in *mp4; do 
    newName=$(sed -E 's/(([^.]*\.){2}).*\.([^.]*)$/\1\3/' <<<"$f"); 
    echo mv -- "$f" "$newName"; 
done
```

If that looks right, run again without the `echo`.